# onListItemClick method not working

Tags: java, android, list

I'm trying to use `SherlockListFragment` with a custom made adapter and the onListItemClick method isn't working. I can't click the list at all. Can someone help me fix my `onListItemClick` method?

```
public class Wallpaper extends SherlockListFragment implements
    OnItemClickListener {
WallpaperAdapter wAdapter;
ArrayList<WallpaperHolder> wallpapers;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    wallpapers = new ArrayList<WallpaperHolder>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        final int pos = i;
        wallpapers.add(new WallpaperHolder() {
            {
                title = "Title" + pos;
                location = "";
            }
        });
    }
    wAdapter = new WallpaperAdapter(getActivity(), wallpapers);
    setListAdapter(wAdapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_wallpaper, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}

public void PassIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageViewDialog.class);
    intent.putExtra("LOC", "/storage/sdcard/pic/Desert.jpg");
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OnItemClick", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The layout of the wallpaper SherlockListFragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FAFAFA"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Wallpaper" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="151dp" >
</ListView>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Enable wallpaper Changer" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_images" />
```

the adapter code

```
public class WallpaperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<WallpaperHolder> wallpapers;
List<WallpaperHolder> wallpapers2;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context c;
public WallpaperAdapter(Context context,List<WallpaperHolder> wallHolder){
    this.wallpapers = wallHolder;
    this.wallpapers2 = wallHolder;
    this.c = context;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return wallpapers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stubs
    WallpaperHolder item = wallpapers.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_row, null);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.deleteButtonWallpaper);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    txtTitle.setText(item.title);
    final int pos = position;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            wallpapers.remove(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

}

simple row.xml

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/deleteButtonWallpaper"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/deleteButtonWallpaper"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteButtonWallpaper"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: just added my adapter code

Comment: post `wallpaper_row.xml`. my guess you have a view that take focus when you click on list item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root element in the xml that you inflate in `getView`

My guess is ImageButton takes focus on click of list row.

Comment: yep,it fixed it,thanks man.and by the way the method that works is the onItemClick and not the onListItemClick

Answer (score 0):

onListItemClick only called if row has not click-able child in it.

Code snipt from code

```
final int pos = position;
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            wallpapers.remove(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Your view has onClickListener, so onListItemClick will not work any more.

But There is workaround for such things, you make whole view click-able and set position as Tag of view.

Comment: hey man,i temporary deleted this listener,but still the list is unclickable.any other options?

Comment: @user2892143 check my post and add the same to the relative layout

Comment: remove click-able view from listView row, then your onListItem.. work